# How to search for specific attribute of multiple XML nodes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Bear with me, I'm new to manipulating XML using jQuery.

Say I have an XML document that looks something like this:

```
<sitemap>
  <products name="products" url="/products.html">
     <shirts name="women's shirts" url="/womens-shirts.html">
     <shoes name="women's shoe" url="/womens-shoes.html">
     <pants....>
  </products>
  <services>
     <shopping>
     <consultation>
  </services>
</sitemap>
```

etc., where each child node of  has both a name and a URL (I'm populating a breadcrumb based on window.location.pathname). I want to search for a specific URL (it should match whatever page you're on), which can be in any node, either parent or child. How do I do this without specifying the node I am searching under?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify any element name, use an asterisk:

```
*[url='/products.html']
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
  url: "/_assets/xml/sitemap.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  error: function(){alert('Error loading XML document');},
  success: parseXML
});

function parseXML(xml) {

  var pathname = window.location.pathname;

$(xml).find(*[url=pathname]).each(function()
 {
 
  alert(url);

 });
 }
});